# C++ How do I print a wstring?

Tags: visual-c++, operator-keyword, iostream, wstring

I'm working with a C++ library that returns wstrings from some functions. When I attempt to print them to std::cout I get a message that essentially says it can't find an overload for `<<` in `cout << fnReturningWstring();`.
This little piece of code demonstrates the problem. The error line is 14.

Identical code with `L"mumble"` replaced with `"mumble"` and `wstring` replaced with `string` works perfectly.
So my question is "How do I print a wstring?"

```
     1  #include <iostream>
     2  #include <string>
       
     3  using std::wstring;
     4  using std::cout;
       
     5  wstring
     6  world()
     7  {
     8    wstring whirled(L"whirled!");
     9    return whirled;
    10  }
       
    11  int main()
    12  {
    13    cout << L"hello, ";
    14    cout << world();
    15    
    16    return 0;
    17  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change "cout" to "wcout".

Australia, Canada, New Zealand, and the United States are perhaps the only four countries where ASCII just works. I live in Australia. I was unaware that there were "wide" versions of cin, cout, cerr, and clog; wcin, wcout, wcerr, and wclog. I'd also posted on the Visual C++ at Microsoft where a kind person explained it all.